# Missing number inside square with hints

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

[image: Square pattern]

After solving it for days i am exhausted with patterns.

Comment: This is clearly a puzzle you got from somewhere else. Could you please (1) edit it to include enough information to enable others to look up the original source and (2) let us know whether you have the creator's permission to copy it here? Thanks. (I'm going to put it on hold until we have that information.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan , Yes it was taken from a page on Telegram which i admin , So yeah I have permission.

Comment: I don't think I understand. Surely it can't both be true that (1) you're the original source of the puzzle _and_ (2) you've been trying to solve it for days. (Or is the bit about "solving it for days" fictitious and added just for colour?)

Comment: Yeah it is for color and i do have the answer. But first please make it visible.

Comment: OK, I'll take your word for it. Reopening.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) 18+8+6+5=37
>     2) 28+7+5+2=42
>     3) 28+18+5+4=55
>     4) (101+3)-(24+18)=62
>     The missing number is 18.

Comment: I think the missing number is expected to be one of A, B, C, D.